# What is Wiremock and can I use it to test my Rest API in Spring?

Tags: spring, wiremock

I created a REST API with Spring and want to test it. I saw WireMock but I dont really know how this library can help me. Can I use it to test my Rest API or ist it to mock another API my API uses, so that I can ensure that a mistake is coming from my Service?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "want to test it"? How would you be "testing" your API? What would a pass/failure look like?

WireMock is a mock server service. It acts as an API that can feed in responses that you have defined (or even proxy an existing API and feed in responses it gets from there.) I usually use it *in place of* an unreliable API, to act as the back end for the app that I am using.

If you are looking for a library that you can use to ping your API, I've had success using [REST-Assured](http://rest-assured.io/). If you are looking for a program you can use to ping your API, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is my app of choice.